# Firebase - Deep index with dynamic keys in path

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

I was trying to implement a conversation system using firebase.

I'm willing to query like this:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://mine.firebaseio.com/conversations");
ref.orderByChild("partners/" + partnerID + "/is_active").equalTo(true).once("value", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    //do something
});
```

My security rules on 'conversations' is as below.

```
"conversations" : {
  ".read" : true,
  ".write" : true,
  ".indexOn" : "partners/partner_id/is_active",
  "$conversation_id" : {
    ".read" : true,
    ".write" : true,
    "partners" : {
        "$partner_id" : {
          ".indexOn" : "is_active" 
        }
    },
    "messages" : {
       "$message_id" : {
          ".read" : true,
          ".write" : true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now the problem is with ".indexOn" : "partners/partner_id/is_active" that I cannot have $partner_id in it, as it is dynamic key. I tried with "partners/$partner_id/is_active" also but seems like that is not allowed. Also ".indexOn" : "is_active" seems to be of no use to me, as I want to query at 'conversation' level.

I'm looking for any workaround or suggestion on this. Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: this question is about using indexOn in the security rules, why is it marked like identical to a question talking about adding a listener on a path??

Comment: I think the issue here is the actual query. As is, it will only ever query one node *conversations/partners/partner_id_0/is_active* and no other nodes. That being said, if are intentionally trying to get the value for that node, a query isn't needed at all - you can read the node directly since you know the specific path. In other words you're trying to do a [Deep Query](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html) at a dynamic path which really can't be done.